# Create yml file to execute pipeline on teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, teamcity, devops

I've been using Teamcity as CI/CD tool, and I'd like to know if would be possible to create my own yml file in order to execute my pipeline (something like bitbucke-pipelines.yml), I didn't found how to do that in the documentation.

Is there a there something like a "template" to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to use YAML for TeamCity pipeline configuration. Their alternative for configuration as code is `Kotlin DSL`. Reasons are mentioned in the [old documentation](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/kotlin-configuration-scripts-an-introduction/).